# Filtering on multiple customDimensions and then aggregating

Tags: sql, pivot, google-bigquery, analytics, bigdata

The data that comes out from the BigQuery implementation of [GoogleAnalytics raw data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) looks like this:

```
|-visitId
|- date
|- (....)
+- hits
   |- time
   |- page
      |- pagePath
   |- eventInfo
      |- eventAction
   +- customDimensions
      |- index
      |- value
```

I am looking to grab 3 values out from the repeated `customDimensions` like

```
+---------+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
| user_id | country | split | page Hits | CTA event hit |
+---------+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
| 100     | US      | A     | 25000     | 500           |
+---------+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
| 100     | US      | B     | 8000      | 90            |
+---------+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
| 200     | ES      | A     | 400       | 2             |
+---------+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

the first three columns are defined by `hits.customDimensions.index` 1,4,7.

The `page hit` SUM is how many views they did, the `CTA event hit` is sum of the event that is fired if they click a button on a page itself. For the sake of SQL simplicity we can name `hits.page.pagePath='tshirt'` and `hits.eventInfo.eventAction='upsell'`

I am having difficulty reading the 3 customDimensions out from the same repated field, then I am having difficulty locating the events that happened in the same session.

**Update for those that are not familiar with BQ dataset**

In the below image each line is a hit, and multiple hits can be on the same row. In BigQuery that is called REPEATED field. In the image you see 3 taller rows. The first row has 8 hit. The image doesn't contain multiple customDimensions, but that can be multiple for the same hit. To access a sample DB set on BigQuery [read here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416091?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089) it's free.

[image]

Comment: is that the sample data or the expected result you showed?

Comment: expected result

Comment: can you show some sample data please?

Comment: I tried to add some screenshot that visualizes the RECORD and REPEATED type of schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering, I'd like to show the mock data that I used as a guide to come up with a solution, hopefully it will be useful:

```
WITH mock_data AS(
select '0' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(0 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('/home' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '0' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('/randompage' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '0' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(2 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(1 as index, '000' as value), STRUCT(4 as index, 'US' as value), STRUCT(7 as index, 'A' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '0' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(3 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(1 as index, '000' as value), STRUCT(4 as index, 'US' as value), STRUCT(7 as index, 'A' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all

select '1' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(0 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('/home' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '1' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('/randompage' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '1' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(2 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(1 as index, '100' as value), STRUCT(4 as index, 'US' as value), STRUCT(7 as index, 'A' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '1' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(3 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('specific_category' as eventcategory, 'specific_label' as eventlabel, 'upsell' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '1' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(4 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(1 as index, '100' as value), STRUCT(4 as index, 'US' as value), STRUCT(7 as index, 'A' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits  union all

select '2' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(0 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('/home' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '2' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('/randompage' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '2' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(2 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('specific_category' as eventcategory, 'specific_label' as eventlabel, 'upsell' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all

select '3' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(0 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('/home' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '3' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('/randompage' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '3' fullvisitorid, 1 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(2 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(1 as index, '300' as value), STRUCT(4 as index, 'US' as value), STRUCT(7 as index, 'A' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '3' fullvisitorid, 1 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(3 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(1 as index, '300' as value), STRUCT(4 as index, 'US' as value), STRUCT(7 as index, 'A' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all

select '4' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(0 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('/home' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '4' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('/randompage' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '4' fullvisitorid, 0 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(2 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(1 as index, '400' as value), STRUCT(4 as index, 'BR' as value), STRUCT(7 as index, 'B' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '4' fullvisitorid, 1 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(0 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('specific_category' as eventcategory, 'specific_label' as eventlabel, 'upsell' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '4' fullvisitorid, 1 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(1 as index, '400' as value), STRUCT(4 as index, 'BR' as value), STRUCT(7 as index, 'B' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all

select '4' fullvisitorid, 2 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(0 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(1 as index, '400' as value), STRUCT(4 as index, 'BR' as value), STRUCT(7 as index, 'B' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '4' fullvisitorid, 2 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('specific_category' as eventcategory, 'specific_label' as eventlabel, 'upsell' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '4' fullvisitorid, 2 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(2 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('specific_category' as eventcategory, 'specific_label' as eventlabel, 'upsell' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '4' fullvisitorid, 3 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(0 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(1 as index, '400' as value), STRUCT(4 as index, 'BR' as value), STRUCT(7 as index, 'A' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '4' fullvisitorid, 3 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(0 as index, '' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('specific_category' as eventcategory, 'specific_label' as eventlabel, 'upsell' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
select '4' fullvisitorid, 3 visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitnumber INT64, customdimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>, page STRUCT<pagepath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventlabel STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(2 as hitnumber, [STRUCT(1 as index, '400' as value), STRUCT(4 as index, 'BR' as value), STRUCT(7 as index, 'A' as value)] as customdimensions, STRUCT('tshirt' as pagepath) as page, STRUCT('' as eventcategory, '' as eventlabel, '' as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits
)
```

I've simulated 4 distinct users visiting the website using the same schema we find in BigQuery `ga_sessions` table.

Some of my assumptions might be a bit different from your actual data. If this is the case, please let me know and we can adapt the mock data as a guide for more accurate answers (I actually use these mocks to run integration tests in our production environment so they can be helpful).

The assumptions I did was (correct me if I'm wrong):

1. The `customDimensions` are only fired when `hits.page.pagepath=tshirt`
2. They are always fired. That is, every visit to the "tshirt" page corresponds to a triggering of the customs.
3. When the `eventAction` click happens, `customDimensions` are not fired at the same time (i.e, the events are fired in one **hitNumber** and the customized events into another).

This might give the result expected:

```
select
    user_id,
    country,
    _split,
    sum(page_hits) page_hits,
    sum(CTA_event_hit) CTA_event_hit
from(
select
    max(user_id) user_id,
    max(country) country,
    max(_split) _split,
    max(page_hits) page_hits,
    max(CTA_event_hit) CTA_event_hit
from(
select
    fv,
    v,
    user_id,
    country,
    _split,
    count(case when user_id is not null then 1 end) page_hits,
    sum(click_flag) CTA_event_hit
from(
select 
    fullvisitorid fv,
    visitid v,
    (select custd.value from unnest(hits.customdimensions) custd where custd.index = 1) user_id,
    (select custd.value from unnest(hits.customdimensions) custd where custd.index = 4) country,
    (select custd.value from unnest(hits.customdimensions) custd where custd.index = 7) _split,
    case when hits.eventinfo.eventcategory = 'specific_category' and hits.eventinfo.eventlabel = 'specific_label' and hits.eventinfo.eventaction = 'upsell' then 1 end click_flag
from mock_data,
unnest(hits) hits
where 1 = 1
    and hits.page.pagepath = 'tshirt'
)
group by fv, v, user_id, country, _split
)
group by fv, v
having user_id is not null
)
group by user_id, country, _split
```

That results in:

[image]

Basically, the are some `subselect` queries to retrieve **user_id**, **country** and **split**. For every session (**visitid**) the data is aggregated by using the `MAX` operator and finally there's a final aggregation on the user_id, country and split level.

In other to query on your dataset you just need to change `mock_data` to the correspondent `ga_session` desired table.

Not sure if this will solve your problem but might be of some help.

As a final note, it seems like this data is the setup for maybe an AB test or some analyzes of performances for different variations of your site. This being the case, I'd recommend not allowing users to change their **split** value as this can lead to some poisoning of the data (which might skew results).

Comment: pretty much this is complete result, I just had to tune the column names. can you explain the `from mock_data,unnest(hits) hits` construct what was the logic with that

Comment: glad it worked :)!  The `unnest` operation here is used to flatten the results: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays. It's basically a way of "opening" the values inside of the array and being able to query them, as an example the row:
`[{fullvisitorid: 1, visitid: 1, hits: [{hitNumber: 0, type: 'PAGE'}, {hitsNumber: 1, type: 'PAGE'}]]` becomes:
`fullvisitorid: 1, visitid: 1, hits.hitNumber: 0, hits.type: 'PAGE'`
`fullvisitorid:1, visitid:1, hits.hitNumber: 1, hits.type:'PAGE'.`
As you can see, it repeats the values and opens the array

Comment: I know what nest is, but the comma operation is that cross join? and why is that needed?

Comment: yeap, the comma is an alias for the `cross join`. I used it just to be able to run `select` statements inside the **hits** field, otherwise you can't access what's inside it.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I understood the problem, I only provide here solution for computing custom columns and page hits metric, but not (yet) for CTA event hit.
Using sample GA table and Standard SQL, it can look something like this:

```
SELECT 
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT c.product, c.color, 1 page_hits 
  FROM t.hits hit CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(ARRAY(
        SELECT DISTINCT AS STRUCT
          if(dim.index = 1, dim.value, NULL) product,
          if(dim.index = 2, dim.value, NULL) color
        FROM hit.customDimensions dim 
        WHERE dim.index in (1,2))) c
  )
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910` t
```

Basically, in the inner SELECT we convert customDimensions.index into separate columns (product and color in this example), and then the outer SELECT prepares to count them by setting page_hits to 1 for every hit.